# How does wordpress know if i'm logging in with username or email?

Tags: wordpress

I'm in the process of migrating a different site to Wordpress. The original site doesn't have usernames, only email addresses.  I've been told to just make the emails their usernames on Wordpress (which I don't like, but there doesn't seem to be any other option).   But now I wonder how Wordpress decides if I'm logging in with email or a username?

Take this unlikely but possible scenario:

User 1 has username `my_username` and email `mail@mail.com`.

User 2 has username `mail@mail.com` and email `abc@xyz.com`.

If someone tries logging in with `mail@mail.com`, which user does Wordpress try logging in?  And if one fails, would it try the other?